# Spring Boot Shutting down after run for while

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I'm facing this problem error from Spring Cloud Stream GCP

EventDrivenConsumer - Removing...

I have 5 VM that running same Spring Boot application that use Hikari,Spring Cloud Stream GCP as dependencies.

The application on only 1 VM of 5 is shutting down after run for while

Please see image below for logging

[image]

Comment: Have you defined thread pool size?

Comment: What about Hikari data source configuration for the number of connection, please check that also.

Comment: @Niraj Jha I already define thread pool size and database is fine I monitor with newrelic I think it should not be concern with the database